# Как использовать библиотеку Skia в visual studio

Tags: c++, gui

Как подключить к проекту. На оф сайте(https://skia.org/) смотрел, ничего не понятно.
OS Windows 10
Visual Studio 19

Comment: Я клонировал репозиторий, а дальше не понимаю что делать. Эту страницу читал skia.org/user/build, не понимаю что дальше делать.

Comment: Пишет  No module named 'asset_utils'

Comment: @AlexF Этого делать как раз не надо, так как у опа уже есть Visual Studio 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека спокойно прикручивается нужно сделать всего лишь несколько шагов.

Для компиляции и генерирования проекта для Visual Studio 2019 используется gn.exe приложение, которое располагается по пути skia (или то что вы клонировали)/bin/gn.exe.

Ближе к сути:

1. Открываем консольную строку (Console Command, Win+R->Cmd->Enter). И **переходим** в **корневой** каталог где находится ваша **skia** (К примеру может быть C:/skia/).
2. Пишем: **python2 tools/git-sync-deps**, или просто **python tools/git-sync-deps**
3. После чтобы сгенерировать проект перейдите в корнейвой каталог вашей библиотеки это к примеру может быть C:/skia/ и напишите в консоли

**"bin/gn.exe" gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true extra_cflags=["/MD"]" --ide=vs -std=c++17**

3.1 Если не получился пункт 3 (вернее при компиляции проекта выходят ошибки и невозможно получить skia), то попробуйте следующую команду

**"bin/gn.exe" gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_zlib=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_harfbuzz=false skia_use_expat=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_libwebp_decode=false skia_use_libwebp_encode=false is_component_build=false skia_use_vulkan=true extra_cflags=["/MD"]" --ide=vs -std=c++17**

("bin/gn.exe" обязательно в кавычках иначе не найдёт приложение)

Так оно заранее создаст решение, в котором будет поддерживаться графический API **Vulkan**.

Если вам нужна библиотека которая будет прикрепляться во время линковки с флагом /MT, то **extra_cflags** указывать **не нужно**.
Если вы хотите собрать в **Debug** то поставьте is_official_build=**false**.
Если хотите сгенерировать решение, которое skia будет компилировать не как статическую библиотеку .lib, а .dll то укажите следующий параметр **is_component_build=true**.
После вы можете скомпилировать решение либо через ninja, либо через Visual Studio 2019, ибо решение для вашего редактора было сгенерировано, **но учтите что ninja всё равно нужен будет, поэтому установите его себе**.

Чтобы отличать генерируемые решение после out/ПишитеВашуСборку, на примере выше я называл Release потому что соответствует сути.

Компиляция через ninja (убедитесь что значение Path в системных параметрах системы был указан каталог до приложения, иначе с консоли вам придётся обращаться к полному пути где располагается ninja).
(Из корневого каталога): "ninja -C out/Release"

Надеюсь что помог!

Comment: python tools/git-sync-deps
fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/piex.git/': Empty reply from server...

Comment: Либо стоит использовать master ветку, либо обратиться на форум к разработчикам.

Comment: Использовал master ветку не помогло(

Comment: У вас были такие ошибки ?

Comment: Нет. Возможно вам не хватает depot_tools, но могу ошибаться. Попробуйте обратиться к https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/skia-discuss

Там же посмотрите, нет ли вашей проблемы.